# How can I debug "Build failed: Too many concurrent builds" error when only one function is being deployed via Google Cloud Function?

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, google-cloud-functions, google-developers-console

I'm currently trying to deploy a function via the console. I have added variables, package specs, and service account credentials.

When I hit deploy, the status was in `build` with the spinning wheel for about ten minutes before coming back with a `build failed` icon.

When I went to the logs I am seeing the following:

```
status: {
code: 8
message: "Build failed: Too many concurrent builds, please stagger your deployments."
}
```

with `severity: ERROR` under `resource`.

There are several other cloud functions that are already deployed and active; they were deployed some time ago and are not currently being redeployed.

I have attempted to redeploy the function in question but that resulted in a timeout after 60 seconds.

Full logs below:

```
{
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
status: {
code: 8
message: "Build failed: Too many concurrent builds, please stagger your deployments."
}
authenticationInfo: {
principalEmail: "user@user"
}
serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"
resourceName: "projects/resource_name"
}
insertId: "-n11hqacqvq"
resource: {
type: "cloud_function"
labels: {3}
}
timestamp: "2021-02-18T22:16:56.681559Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/.../logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
operation: {
id: "operations/..."
producer: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
last: true
}
receiveTimestamp: "2021-02-18T22:16:56.858611526Z"
}
```

Comment: Have you your project linked to a billing account? Do you have other deployment in parallel? Did  you have a look to the quotas page?

Comment: This project is linked to a billing account which has a quota of 1000 cloud functions and less than 1% of it used up

Comment: Do you work within an organisation with many teams that deploy on Cloud Functions?

Comment: Okay actually this should be closed since Google Support reached out to me and commented that there were ongoing deployment issues in my region when attempting to deploy. This is no longer an issue but not sure the right way to close.